# Application abnormal behavior does not start activity mentioned in intent

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have 3 major class in the application

1) Intent service: where I receive push notification and open activity according to notification message and other two classes behavior. below is the code which does that

```
 if(Global.isMainScreenRunning){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
   intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
} else if(!Global.NotificationScreenRunning){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationScreen.class);
   intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

2) NotificationScreen : This is the mediator screen so if the application is not running this screen will be shown first and on click of yes button of this screen MainScreen will be opened and this screen will be finished.

3) Main screen: This is the main screen of the application which show map. its core behavior is that ts a `launchmode="singletask"` mentioned in menifest file, which means if this screen is running its hole data will be sent to `onNewIntent()` method rather than opening this screen again.

Now what is happening in flow is

Step 1: application is in background and push notification comes. condition run and the second condition gets success and notification screen intent is shot

step 2: In notification screen I click on ye button to move on to the next main screen

step 3: In Main screen I process this info and perform task or just close the application

Step 4: again a new notification is received and as the application is not running is goes to second condition and start the intent for notification screen but this time no notification screen is launched instead of providing its intent and main screen is launched which is wrong.

This is the abnormal behavior which I am facing that instead of providing class of notification screen for intent main screen is launched which is totally different behavior of application according to android.

Any help from any one who come across such problem will be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/android_app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationScreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".pushnotification.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.selebrety.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".pushnotification.GcmIntentService" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Second Edit**

The mobile in which I am testing is "YU Yureka" here is its specification [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/yu_yureka-6987.php). Current it have android 5.0.2 OS

**Third Edit**

To test this behavior I have debugged the code from eclipse debugger. To check this I have put a break point in `NotificationScreen` `onResume` and `onCreate` but it was never hit instead of `onResume` of `MainScreen` is hit.

Also I added a logs in if and else condition but still logs for else condition is printed.

**Fourth Edit**
`Global.isMainScreenRunning`: is global `boolean` variable which is done false in `onPause` of `MainScreen` and done true in `onResume` of `MainScreen`.

`Global.NotificationScreenRunning`: is global `boolean` variable which is done false in `onPause` of `NotificationScreen` and done true in `onResume` of `NotificationScreen`.

Comment: How is Global.isMainScreenRunning declared?

Comment: public static boolean in global class. This will be true in onResume and false in onPause.

Comment: How have you demonstrated that the second condition is being executed?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Please check my step 4th which says specifies that

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya I know you said that's what's happening, but from the information given, that is most likely not what is happening.  How did you test it?  Did you try putting a log message in that `if` block?

Comment: `startActivity(Intent);` - that can't be right, can it?  Shouldn't it be `startActivity(intent);`?

Comment: That just proves that it's launching `MainScreen`.  I'm asking how you proved that `Global.isMainScreenRunning` is false when you think it is.

Comment: Global.isMainScreenRunning is true in onResume of MainScreen and it is done false in onPause of MainScreen

Comment: But what is its value at the line `if(Global.isMainScreenRunning){...}`, and have you tested and proved this?

Comment: application is closed so its false. I tested it by debugging and also putting logs and still the else part runs. It prints always Global.isMainScreenRunning as false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83107/discussion-between-abhinav-singh-maurya-and-kevin-krumwiede).

Comment: Try to remove `excludeFromRecents` from `NotificationActivity`, and give it a try, does it work then?

Comment: @Darpan I have tried these thing and removed 'excludeFromRecents' but no change

Answer (score 0):

Global state is evil, and this question demonstrates why.  To understand what's happening, you'll have to look at every place where your global flags are set or cleared, and analyze all the possible execution paths that might lead there.  That's way beyond the scope of the kind of help you can get on SO.  And there's an extra complication on Android, since the entire VM might be destroyed (and all your globals cleared) any time your app is in the background.  Just as bad, the VM and the `Application` instance might be retained after you exit the last activity.  When that happens, `Application#onCreate(...)` will not be called again the next time you start the app, and all your `static` globals will still be set to whatever they were when you last ran the app.

Save yourself a lot of hair-pulling and stop using global state.

Comment: I believe you have not read the question correctly. Please read question and let me know the answer. And by the way problem is not with the global variable its with the intent not starting correct activity

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya  believe you have not read the answer correctly.  Your question is *unanswerable* without an analysis of every read or write of `Global.isMainScreenRunning` and `Global.NotificationScreenRunning` in your entire app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `android:taskAffinity=":main"` to your MainScreen activity in manifest.
Maybe because the MainScreen still in a same task with the NotificationScreen so it's was call up all the task when NotificationScreen called again.
You can try this demo for more visual:
[play app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode) and [code](https://github.com/gnorsilva/Activities-LaunchMode-demo)
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

As I got your point you want to resume Notification Screen every time when you get notification in the app.For this I can suggest a solution this will make the application runs and allows you to achieve expected behavior but when you press home button your Main screen will no longer active.It will be killed.As we all know android maintains activity stacks for all acticities.So if you press device back button then activity will be poped out from stack and you will not face this problem.

I think this is a standard behavior of activity stacks for more information you can go with this link:

http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack

You can try this code snippet:

```
Intent i = new Intent(NotificationFullScreen.this,
      MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("FROM", "Notification");
    i.putExtra("bookingId", bookingId);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
      | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    startActivity(i);
    NotificationFullScreen.this.finish();
```

Comment: what a presentation done by Ran Nachmany. I was not knowing the behavior mentioned in the presentation and sides from 91-101 explain the exact behavior I am facing with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Thanks for the reply. I resolved the problem with the flags you have mentioned. but yes my MainScreen will be killed after moving away from it but what can be done with the default behavior. Your answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hi @Abhinbav Singh Maurya

I think the problem is that main screen is getting called from your splash screen declared in the manifest as the application launch screen, so when the app is killed and you are calling the intent this will get called.

Instead of that what can you do is broadcast the message to the splash screen and receive it in splash screen and based on condition call the intent from there.

Again here there is a thing that you should take care of, you have to broad cast the intent only after the receiver is registered in the SplahScreen, else it will never be received. so try to user handler.postDelayed method and broadcast after 1000 ms or 700 ms.

```
 Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class);
                mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(mIntent);
broadcastMessage(context, message);
```

I have answered a similar question in the following thread. 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618321/open-android-activity-automatically-on-receiving-notification/31287040#31287040)

I think this is what you are looking for. Please let me know if this met your requirement or not, if you find the answer useful, if my answer helps you, up vote the answer so that it will be useful to others.

Cheers :)

Edit

I have did a bit research on it.

You can have two launcher activities according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927315/two-launcher-activities) link.

Try it and let me know. Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: please check my question correctly I have not mentioned mainscreen as launch screen I have declared its launch mode as single task. There is lot of difference between them.

Comment: can you post your manifest here. In your question you mentioned that the MainScreen is the mainscreen of the application.. So what is the reason to downvote the answer?

Comment: Now when the application is not running and you try to call intent, your 'SplashScreen' will be loaded as per my knowledge. So Obviously your splash screen will start and load your 'MainScreen'. So you need to broadcast the intent from Intent service and receive it in splashscreen and take next action accordingly. That's what my answer said. I assumed that your MainScreen is your launch screen, so please try it and let me know.

Comment: Could you please let me know why splash screen will open if I am providing intent a class of notification scree. Is there any specification that only launcher screen can be open from intent service not and ordinary screen?

Comment: Yes cannot open any screen other than launcher screen if the app is not running, That's why mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); and launch the launcher activity and broadcast message. If you can open any other activity other than launcher activity when the app is killed, you can ask even your friends to down vote my answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83015/discussion-between-abhinav-singh-maurya-and-sravan).

Comment: please check my question once again before answering. I have an intent service running in background. application is closed as soon as push notification is received I open my application specific activity "notification screen". You can open any activity outside the application using new_task flag, so for me outside is intent service for receiving push notification.

Comment: I have checked your question. You are starting an activity in the OnMessage of the GCMIntentService... That's what I understood.. Am I correct?

Answer (score -2):

```
if(Global.isMainScreenRunning){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
   intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(Intent);//here is the problem change Intent to intent 

} else if(!Global.NotificationScreenRunning){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationScreen.class);
   intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: That is not my problem. Please read question carefully and follow the steps that I have mentioned there

Comment: i think you want to say that first time app works normal but when app complete its first cycle it behaves abnormal

Comment: Exactly. Like when you run an open app in eclipse without any change its says its previous task is bring to front, that sort of behavior I am feeling with the app

Comment: I think that when you close your app from main screen the system closes the app completely so it can't check such condition but at first when the app launches onCreate() runs and check these conditions

Comment: I checked the conditions of OnCreate and onResume of NotificationScreen but non of them hit.

Comment: can you provide the complete code of your app?  or you have check these conditions contineously in background of your app that checks the condition  at some time intervals

Comment: I have check these condition as soon as push notification is received in intent service. I have provided the flow and what happening. sorry I cannot provide the full source code